# Getting CMIS runtime exception while getting the document in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am trying to get the content stream of a document present in Alfresco. In order to achieve the same I first created the cmis session as follows (I am using CMIS 1.1)

```
SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, getAtomPublicURL(getRequestFactory()));
parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
parameter.put(SessionParameter.AUTH_HTTP_BASIC, "true");
parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, mUserName);
parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, mPassword);

List<Repository> repositories = factory.getRepositories(parameter);

cmisSession = repositories.get(0).createSession();
```

After creating the session I tried two different methods to access the document

Method 1:(Given the nodeRef of the document in Alfresco)

```
String objectId = "f273be7c-9b70-44cf-880f-5945a7857b5d";
CmisObject cmisObject = cmisSession.getObject(objectId);
```

Method 2:(Given the path of the document)

```
String objectPath = "/Sites/testSite/documentLibrary/testFolder1/testFolder2/testDocument.pdf";
CmisObject cmisObject = cmisSession.getObjectByPath(objectPath);
```

Note: testSite is the site name in which my document is present.

Unfortunately both the methods are throwing me a CMIS runtime exception

> (org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Internal Server Error).

UPDATE:
Hey Jeff I have made REST api call to add tags after the creation of document.Though the tags are added I feel like it creates some lock to the document.Thats why I couldn't able to get the Document object from Alfresco(when trying to get the document object gives me Internal server error as I mentioned in the question).When I removed the tag adding logic I am able to retrieve the Document object from Alfresco without issues.Below is my method that add tags to the document.

```
public void setTags(String documentId,ArrayList<String> Tags) throws Exception {
    final String methodName = "setTags";
    try{
        GenericUrl containersUrl = new GenericUrl(getAlfrescoAPIUrl() +
                                             getHomeNetwork() +
                                             mNODES_URL +
                                             documentId +
                                             "/tags");
        mLog.debug(containersUrl);
        String tagName = "";
        String appendTags = "";

        for(int index=0;index<Tags.size();index++){
            tagName = (String) Tags.get(index);
            appendTags = appendTags+"{\"tag\": \""+tagName+"\"}";
            if(index < Tags.size()-1){
                appendTags = appendTags+",";
            }
        }

        String finalTags = "["+appendTags+"]";

        HttpContent body = new ByteArrayContent("application/json", finalTags.getBytes());
        HttpRequest request = getRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(containersUrl, body);
        try{
            request.execute();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            mLog.error("Exception in :: "+mClassName+":: "+methodName+":: "+ioException.getMessage());
            throw ioException;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        mLog.error("Exception in :: "+mClassName+":: "+methodName+":: "+exception.getMessage());
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a custom method to fetch the AtomPub URL. Can you output that to make sure it looks like this:
http://alfresco.local:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom

Also, you might dump the value of cmisSession.getRepositoryInfo().getProductName() and cmisSession.getRepositoryInfo().getProductVersion() just to make sure that worked okay. Mine shows:

```
Alfresco Community
5.2.0 (re21f2be5-b22)
```

Assuming both of those debug steps worked, both of your methods work as shown on my machine.

A small nitpick is that the value you have set to objectId is not a CMIS object ID but is part of an Alfresco node ref (a full nodeRef includes "workspace://SpacesStore/"). Alfresco will handle what you are passing in, assuming that node actually exists.

Check the alfresco log to see what the exception being thrown says. The log is in /opt/alfresco/tomcat/logs/catalina.out.

Comment: Hey Jeff, I had made sure my custom method to fetch the atom public url is returning like  http://alfresco.local:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom.Also I tested my cmis session using the methods you have mentioned.
cmisSession.getRepositoryInfo().getProductName() gives me Alfresco Community and cmisSession.getRepositoryInfo().getProductVersion() gives me 4.2.0 (r63893-b12).From this I can confirm that there is no problem with the created cmis session.However when I try to use getObject methods I am getting the same error.

Comment: I also confirmed that the document is present in Alfresco and even if the document is not present it would have thrown me CMISObjectNotFound exception if I am not wrong.I have posted the error in detail below   

   Caused by: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Internal Server Error

at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:487) [chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

Comment: at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.read(AbstractAtomPubService.java:613) [chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.getObjectInternal(AbstractAtomPubService.java:836) [chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.getObject(ObjectServiceImpl.java:619) [chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

Comment: at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:410) [chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.getObject(SessionImpl.java:388) [chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]

Comment: Does everything work when you use Chemistry Workbench to access your server?